# Troubles setting up RayLib on VScode on Windows11 for C++ programming

Tags: c++, debugging, raylib

I'm having issues setting up Raylib on VScode and I think the problem stands in the debugging part of the process:

```
#include <raylib.h>

    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib");

    camera.position = (Vector3){10.0f, 10.0f, 8.0f};
    camera.target = (Vector3){0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    camera.up = (Vector3){0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
    camera.fovy = 60.0f;
    camera.projection = CAMERA_PERSPECTIVE;


    SetTargetFPS(60);
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        UpdateDrawFrame();
    }[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Frm.png)


    CloseWindow(); // Close window and OpenGL context
    
    return 0;
}

static void UpdateDrawFrame(void)
{
    UpdateCamera(&camera, CAMERA_ORBITAL);
    
    BeginDrawing();

    ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

    BeginMode3D(camera);

    DrawCube(cubePosition, 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, RED);
    DrawCubeWires(cubePosition, 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, MAROON);
    DrawGrid(10, 1.0f);

    EndMode3D();

    DrawText("This is a raylib example", 10, 40, 20, DARKGRAY);

    DrawFPS(10, 10);

    EndDrawing();
}
```

When I try to run this code (a basic example you can find [here](https://www.raylib.com/examples.html)) with F5 and the extension *.c* I face no trouble and everything works fine, but as soon as I change the file extension to *.cpp*, I receive this message:
[Debugging with *.cpp* extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjLvx.png) .

On the default console I have this output:

```
Executing task in folder VSCode: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\mingw32-make.exe RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib PROJECT_NAME=main OBJS=main.c BUILD_MODE=DEBUG 

mingw32-make main
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/raylib projects/VSCode'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'main.c', needed by 'main'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/raylib projects/VSCode'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:372: all] Error 2

 *  The terminal process "C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\mingw32-make.exe 'RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib', 'PROJECT_NAME=main', 'OBJS=main.c', 'BUILD_MODE=DEBUG'" terminated with exit code: 2.
```

I don't know if you need also the tasks.json and/or the c_cpp_properties.json but i'll add them as well:

Tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build debug",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "PLATFORM=PLATFORM_DESKTOP",
                "BUILD_MODE=DEBUG",
                "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "OBJS=${fileBasenameNoExtension}.c"
            ],
            "windows": {
                "command": "mingw32-make.exe",
                "args": [
                    "RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib",
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "OBJS=${fileBasenameNoExtension}.c",
                    "BUILD_MODE=DEBUG"
                ]
            },
            "osx": {
                "args": [
                    "RAYLIB_PATH=<path_to_raylib>/raylib",
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "OBJS=${fileBasenameNoExtension}.c",
                    "BUILD_MODE=DEBUG"
                ]
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "build release",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "PLATFORM=PLATFORM_DESKTOP",
                "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "OBJS=${fileBasenameNoExtension}.c"
            ],
            "windows": {
                "command": "mingw32-make.exe",
                "args": [
                    "RAYLIB_PATH=C:/raylib/raylib",
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "OBJS=${fileBasenameNoExtension}.c"
                ]
            },
            "osx": {
                "args": [
                    "RAYLIB_PATH=<path_to_raylib>/raylib",
                    "PROJECT_NAME=${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                    "OBJS=${fileBasenameNoExtension}.c"
                ]
            },
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": ["C:/raylib/raylib/src/**", "${workspaceFolder}/**"],
      "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE",
        "GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33",
        "PLATFORM_DESKTOP"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "c99",
      "cppStandard": "c++14",
      "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

I've been following tutorial on yt for the past 3/4 days and it's getting really frustrating because it seems like no tutorial can solve my problem, or maybe it's just my stupid ass that can't get it to work, I'm considering switching to Visual Studio but i'd like to stick on VSCode

The last one I found was [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaAcVk5jUd8) (don't know if this may help you identifying what the problem is)

Comment: are you using c or c++? Does `main.c` exist or are you using `main.cpp`? `No rule to make target 'main.c'` means that `main.c` doesn't exist and no make rule will generate it

Comment: The error message is telling you that `main.c` does not exist, well that's because you renamed it to `main.cpp`

Comment: Presumably that means you need to change `"OBJS=${fileBasenameNoExtension}.c"` to `"OBJS=${fileBasenameNoExtension}.cpp"` in `tasks.json` (three different places). If you use VSCode you need to gain some understanding of how it turns the choices you make into commands that will be executed to build and run your code.

Comment: @alan the original template has a _.c_ file but the guy in the video said that the configuration should work with c++ too... probably i didn't specify this in the post but I want to code in C++, not C

Comment: @Anto Well it seems the guy is wrong, since the tasks.json explicitly mentions .c files. Youtube videos aren't always the greatest quality. However, I'm just looking at what you posted, I know nothing about raylib.

Comment: @john that worked for me! thank you very much... i thought of switching every _.c_  i could find in those files to _cpp_  but I was afraid of creating new problems.
Yeah it seems like he is... again, thank you very much hope you'll have a great day!

Comment: @Anto You really do need to get some understanding of how those files work, so you aren't guessing.

Comment: @john I know, it's that I am just beginning to learn and i'm just not this good yet

Comment: @Anto Personally I would never recommend VSCode for beginners, it's too complicated. But it is popular.

Comment: There are lots of conflicting things is your json settings. My advice is to install raylib using `pacman` and use only the MinGW you have installed from msys2. The page for ucrt64 `raylib` in msys2 is here: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-raylib?repo=ucrt64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-raylib?repo=ucrt64) The install command is `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-raylib` you type this in a msys2 terminal.